# Python how to include a string with random integer

Tags: python, string, random, numbers

I want to make a random police unit generator and the code is like so:

```
import random
unitnumbers = ('unit' , random.randint(1,999))
print(unitnumbers)
```

However, rather than printing "unit 63" , it prints ('unit', 378)

How could I make it print only the unit and random number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making the value of `unitnumbers` a tuple. You should instead make it a string like that:

```
unitnumbers = "unit " + str(random.randint(1,999))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do that:

```
import random
unitnumbers = 'unit %d' % random.randint(1,999)
print(unitnumbers)
```